# Rewrite DB2 trigger as PostgreSQL Trigger

Tags: postgresql, db2, database-trigger

I'm trying to migrate the following trigger from DB2 to PostgreSQL:

DB2 Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
WHEN (N.field1 <> O.field1)
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2)
VALUES (N.field1, O.field2);
END #
```

I rewrote the trigger to PostgreSQL standard (not sure if it is correct):

PostgreSQL Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table1_history() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $table1_history$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO table1 
                SELECT 
                NEW.field1, OLD.field2;
            RETURN OLD;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$table1_history$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_table1_history();
```

Now I am not sure how to add the following condition in my PostgreSQL Trigger?

```
WHEN (N.field1 <> O.field1)
```

Comment: In your trigger: `IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND NEW.field1 <> OLD.field2 THEN`. Although you really don't need to check `TG_OP` because you've defined your trigger to only be called on update, right?

Comment: Beware of NULLs...

Comment: I don't understand the trigger. Why do you insert the values that are updated into the table that is being updated?

Comment: Ah sorry it should be `INSERT INTO history_table`

Answer (score 2):

you can add a condition on when the trigger is fired:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (new.field1 <> old.field1)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_table1_history();
```

If the column can contain NULL values, it might be better to use

```
    WHEN (new.field1 IS DISTINCT FROM old.field1)
```

---

The trigger function can be simplified as well as you don't need to check TG_OP as the trigger itself is defined to only fire on UPDATEs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table1_history() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$table1_history$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO history_table
   values (NEW.field1, OLD.field2);
   RETURN OLD;
END;
$table1_history$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if:

```
IF (NEW.field1 <> OLD.field1) THEN
     IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
```